# Valid visa on old passport, one time going to Canada

Tags: indian-citizens

I am Indian passport holder, i have Canada visa stamped on old passport, as per PoE letter mentioned I need to apply for visa again if have new passport. Please advise

Comment: What does "PoE" mean here?

Comment: @HenningMakholm generally, at least in the context of travel, it's "port of entry" but I doubt that clarifies much.  Anita: what letter mentioned that you need a new visa?  Why and from whom did you receive that letter?  What kind of visa do you have? What is its expiration date? Where are you now? When and why are you planning to enter Canada?

Comment: @phoog: Yes -- I'm asking because that unfolding doesn't really seem to make sense in the context here.

Comment: @HenningMakholm perhaps this sheds some light on the matter: http://www.cic.gc.ca/english/helpcentre/answer.asp?qnum=845&top=15

Comment: Hi Henning, it’s a letter which I need to show to the port of entry border security officer in Canada, I applied for 2 years work permit. I have approved work permit and visa which I got stamped on my old passport and later I got new passport. Visa will expire on March 2018. I am from India but working in Dubai so applied visa from Dubai. The only issue now that the letter which I need to show to border security officer is mentioned that if you apply for new passport you need to have new visa.

Answer (score 5):

Your [PoE letter](http://www.cic.gc.ca/english/helpcentre/answer.asp?qnum=845&top=15) is an official letter from the Canadian immigration authority saying that you have been approved for a particular kind of permit or visa to stay in Canada in some capacity *other than as a tourist or business visitor.*

As such, it stands to reason that your earlier visa may not be applicable to your future visit, especially if it is a regular visitor's visa.

But reason aside, you report that your PoE letter

> mentioned I need to apply for visa again if have new passport.

If that is true, nobody here can contradict that requirement.  You might try asking a Canadian government official if you can use your old visa, but if the letter says explicitly that you cannot, it's unlikely that anyone will tell you anything different.

Answer (score 3):

I have a POE letter with the same thing.  I freaked out upon finding out as I was suppose to fly to Canada during the week for my study permit.  However I emailed the Embassy and they told me I can travel with both.  And I did travel with both old passport with the valid visa inside and new passport.

Greetings from Vancouver.  With study permit.  Just posting for future individuals like me.